# Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for CustomUser

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/account/customuser/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 642, in get_form
    return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 543, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 252, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (password2, password1) specified for CustomUser

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 128, in add_view
    extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1509, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1438, in changeform_view
    ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 82, in get_form
    return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\Andriken\Documents\Prac\djangoexample\bookmarks\mysite_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 646, in get_form
    % (e, self.__class__.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (password2, password1) specified for CustomUser. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.
[07/Jul/2018 21:14:51] "GET /admin/account/customuser/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 182719
```

forms.py ---------------------------------------

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from account.models import CustomUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('email','date_of_birth',)
        model= CustomUser

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('email','password','date_of_birth','is_active','is_admin')

def clean_password(self):
    return self.initial['password']
```

admin.py-------------

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from account.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, ExtendedUserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
```

## Register your models here.

```
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserCreationForm
    add_form = UserChangeForm
    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin','is_active')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_active',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('date_of_birth','email','password1','password2')}
         ),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()



admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Please anyone try to let me know where am I missing something, I can't solve this, I also tried overriding the UserCreationForm for both Password1 and Password2 fields again to see if it works, but no luck. Seems it's the same

Comment: Post `CustomUser` code, cauze the problem is in there `Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for CustomUser`

Comment: how could the issue be In CustomUser, cause the password1 and password2 fields aren't specified on there, these both fields are just an extra fields supposed to be defined In my UserCreationForm, It's django's standard functionality that extra specified form fields must render In template but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `CustomUserAdmin` try switching `form` and `add_form` values

**Try:**

```
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
```

**`add_form` for creation of new users.**
**`form` for editing**

I hope this will help.

Comment: Dude, you are genius' Shame on me' Oh god It works finally, even after all those django project official django auth customization guide, I made a silly mistake. I should die In shame now :p

Comment: @Andrikensonwane you're welcome. nah that happens all the time. please consider upvote, and accept the answer. happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `password1` and `password2` in fieldsets and `add_fieldsets` with simply `password`.